# On OpenSea, if buyer makes an offer and seller accepts, does the sale go through?

Tags: nft

On OpenSea, if a listing has an offer, will that sale automatically go through (the buyer is charged) once the seller accepts? Or does the buyer at that point have a chance to decline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make an offer, you're allowing OpenSea to spend the chosen amount of ERC20 tokens on your behalf. Once the seller accepts the offer, OpenSea will charge your wallet and send the amount to the seller and you receive your NFT.

Only thing you can do is cancel your offer before the seller accepts it.